# Standalone Policy Automation / Rules Engine for Service Cloud

Tags: integration, rules-engine

I am currently working on a project still in the requirements phase, and trying to figure out  various policy automation tools that integrate with Salesforce.com. I have looked at [OPA](http://www.oracle.com/us/industries/public-sector/058991.html) (Oracle Policy Automation) but I am looking for some competitors which would have *better integration with Salesforce*.

A couple of things I am looking for when I talk about Policy Automation tools:

***1.*** Standalone Rules Engine / Policy Automation Engine that can well integrate with Salesforce and can fire from multiple objects and RecordTypes. 
***2.*** It needs to be an on premise solution.

> **Above 2 are a must**.

I am also open to hear if anyone has ***integrated OPA with Salesforce***. I have not found any documentation on this but I will appreciate your help on this!

Comment: Why **2**? That's not very cloudy.

Comment: I've removed the (very redundant) salesforce-crm tag and the oracle tag. While one of your examples is oracle, the question appears to not be specific to oracle solutions, so it didn't appear correctly tagged to me.

Comment: On top of my above comment, we try to focus on specific problems and solutions, questions like these are very broad and subjective to many factors.